# SubView Not adjusting to my given size

Tags: iphone, subview

I am adding a subview (which is a class's view) to my view.i have fixed it's size to 320, 200 but still it resizes to the full screen when i run my program.

How to do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[<view> setClipsToBounds:YES]
```

Will restrict the subview's bounds to its superview

Comment: +1 thank you ..but now it made that sub view too small...Is there any method to show a particular area or a particular subview of that subview

Comment: - (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
You can implement the above method in your subview and return the appropriate rect.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify `autoresizesSubviews` and `autoresizingMask` properties of the view and subViews. I have faced similar issues and it was due to these properties which made my subViews to resize.